# Cron Job failure

Tags: cron

Since installing a later version of 4.6.x the cron job fails as shown in the attached image. Oddly enough the Bounces Processor continues to function and all of the Scheduled jobs can be run manually successfully.

No changes have been made to the configuration other than upgrading to later releases of CiviCRM.

I am using Drupal 7.39 and CiviCRM 4.6.8.

[image: URL and resulting error]

Comment: Did you attach the image? I don't see it...

Comment: Hmmm - I forgot but I have added it to the original post

Answer (score 1):

This issue was fixed in https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-16584 (4 days ago) and here's the patch https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/6744/files . So please wait for the next 4.6.9 release. Thanks :)

Comment: This is still not working in 4.7.1.